# Pass tags to data frame within function

Tags: r

I'm new at R and have a pretty simple question. I'd like to make a function like:

```
myfunc <- function(tag, value){
  data.frame(tag = value)
}
```

And pass it:

```
myfunc(example, 10)
```

But what I get is:

```
Error in data.frame(tag = value) : object 'example' not found
```

And what Id like to get is:

```
  example
1      10
```

In other words, its not interpreting my input as the tag I want. Is there a good way around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do so telling us that may result in better answers but you need to quote "exampe" as follows:

```
myfunc <- function(tag, value){
  setNames(data.frame(value), tag)
} 

myfunc("example", 10)
```

Or use `as.character(substitute())` which is usually not a good idea:

```
myfunc <- function(tag, value){
  setNames(data.frame(value), as.character(substitute(tag)))
} 

myfunc(example, 10)
```